# How can I jump to another div with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a Q&A website. I want to jump to another question when user picked an answer.

Here is my html code:

```
<div id="question1" >
　　<label>What do you like：</label>
　　<input type="radio" name ="a" value="apple" >apple
　　<input type="radio" name ="a" value="banana">banana
　　<input type="radio" name ="a" value="melon">melon
</div>
```

Here is my Javascript code:

```
var a=document.getElementsByName('a');
var questionNum = 0;

if(a[0].checked)
{
//jump to question2 on same site(or a new site e.g. 2.html)
}
if(a[1].checked)
{
//jump to question3 on same site(or a new site e.g. 3.html)
}
if(a[2].checked)
{
//jump to question4 on same site(or a new site e.g. 4.html)
}
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to identify each question with a unique `id` attribute.
Then you can jump to the question by changing the address by using `location.href = "#question2"`.
You can make this transition smoothly by using the method described in the link below:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp

Answer (score 0):

If the next question is on the same page you can use the following

```
location.href = "#question2";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a nice aproach to your question:

HTML:

```
  <label>What do you like：</label>
  <input type="radio" name="a" value="apple" onclick="check()" />apple
  <input type="radio" name="a" value="banana" onclick="check()" />banana
  <input type="radio" name="a" value="melon" onclick="check()" />melon
</div>
<div id="question2" style="display: none;">
  <label>What do you like：</label>
  <input type="radio" name="a" value="Lorem" />Lorem
  <input type="radio" name="a" value="Ipsum" />Ipsum
  <input type="radio" name="a" value="Dolor" />Dolor
</div>
<div id="question3" style="display: none;">
  <label>What do you like：</label>
  <input type="radio" name="a" value="Lorem" />Lorem
  <input type="radio" name="a" value="Ipsum" />Ipsum
  <input type="radio" name="a" value="Dolor" />Dolor
</div>
<div id="question4" style="display: none;">
  <label>What do you like：</label>
  <input type="radio" name="a" value="Lorem" />Lorem
  <input type="radio" name="a" value="Ipsum" />Ipsum
  <input type="radio" name="a" value="Dolor" />Dolor
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var a = document.getElementsByName("a");
var questionNum = 0;

//Get every question by ID
var question1 = document.getElementById("question1");
var question2 = document.getElementById("question2");
var question3 = document.getElementById("question3");
var question4 = document.getElementById("question4");

//This function runs onclick of the radio-button
function check() {
  if (a[0].checked) {
    //Hide question 1, display question 2
    question1.style.display = "none";
    question2.style.display = "block";
  }
  if (a[1].checked) {
    //Hide question 1, display question 3
    question1.style.display = "none";
    question3.style.display = "block";
  }
  if (a[2].checked) {
    //Hide question 1, display question 4
    question1.style.display = "none";
    question4.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

Further explaination:
At first only the #question1 is visible, the rest has "display: none"
Onclick of one of the radiobuttons you hide the current question, and reveal the next one, depending on the answer

This could be compacted more using "for loops" ect. but for a small scale project this will to the trick.